# Selected state for home page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a selected state using jQuery. I have all pages exept for home page as there is no unique page identifier (i.e) www.abcd.co.nz

JS Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zangief007/1ta4gxwn/

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("/") > -1) {
    $("header ul li a.home").addClass("tn-selected");
}

if (window.location.href.indexOf("about") > -1) {
    $("header ul li a.about").addClass("tn-selected");
}

if (window.location.href.indexOf("links") > -1) {
    $("header ul li a.links").addClass("tn-selected");
}

if (window.location.href.indexOf("contact") > -1) {
    $("header ul li a.contact").addClass("tn-selected");
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zangief007/1ta4gxwn/

Comment: Can you not just put it in a switch statement and make the default one home? (or an if / else statement and the last `else` be the home one)

Comment: [Semi-irrelevant] Why are you using unique classes on your anchors? ID is there for a reason. +1 @putvande [Switch Statements](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp)

Comment: I'm not sure why you accepted greenish's answer, it doesn't fix the problem at all, it simply rewords your current code. If you only wanted a code review you should have posted this to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: It's easy, he had a problem and I solved it.. nothing more.

Comment: Check out the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/1ta4gxwn/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do something like this?

```
var selector = "a.home";

if(window.location.href.indexOf("about") > -1) {
    selector = "a.about";
}
else if(window.location.href.indexOf("links") > -1) {
    selector = "a.links";
} 
else if(window.location.href.indexOf("contact") > -1) {
    selector = "a.contact";
} 

$("header ul li "+selector).addClass("tn-selected");
```

Use `a.home` as default value?

Answer (score 0):

Based entirely on your JSFiddle demo:

#### JavaScript Issue

Your jQuery selectors look for an `a.about` element within a `li`, within a `ul`, within a `header`. Your JSFiddle demo has no `header` element.

#### CSS Issue

After correcting your jQuery selectors your new classes do get applied, however your CSS is invalid as it has oddly placed commas. The style is never applied.

Change:

```css
a.about.tn-selected,
a.contact.tn-selected,
, /* Remove this. */
a.links.tn-selected,
, /* ...and this. */
a.home.tn-selected{
    color:#333;
}
```

To:

```css
a.about.tn-selected,
a.contact.tn-selected,
a.links.tn-selected,
a.home.tn-selected {
    color:#333;
}
```

Or just:

```
a.tn-selected {
    color:#333;
}
```